# once again div vs tables

Tags: html, css, html-tag-details, html-tag-summary

In my project, I have come across a situation where we have to create table (expandable).
I have implemented using divs and spans.
my senior is asking ti implement it using td,tr

```
<div class="header"><div class="colLabel" style="width: 24%;">continent</div><div class="colLabel" style="width: 24%;">country</div><div class="colLabel" style="width: 24%;">population</div><div class="colLabel" style="width: 24%;">gdp</div></div>
```

my implementation is http://jsfiddle.net/agasthyanavaneeth/eLf5K/6/embedded/result/ 
please help me 
thanks :)

Comment: How are we supposed to help? It looks like a table, it should probably be done as a table...

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here.

Comment: @Fred: I am asking about general preference of implementing that type of component(plz check the JSFiddle link I provided).

Comment: Ah I see!  In this example I would say tables as tables are meant for displaying tabular data.  However that is just my opinion I dare say this is an argument that will never end!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes use a table for tabular data rather than a generic `<div>`.  You could also use the new `HTML5` tags: `<details>` and `<summary>`

Then do something like the following:

```
<details>
   <summary>Continent name</summary>
    <p>Country, population and gdp content here</p>
</details>
```

http://html5doctor.com/the-details-and-summary-elements/

Answer (score 1):

Although you might have heard tables arent to be used on a website... it just means you shouldnt use them to create a layout for your page.

If you have to show data, or somehow use a raster, most of the time a table is just best.
If you want to build a page, use div's.

If you have a more specific question, feel free to ask!

ps: I think your teacher is right, from what i can see. You want to show data in a raster/table like page. just use tables, its meant for it.

Answer (score 0):

You example looks to me like the ideal application for a `<table>` element. It's tabular data. To see where I'm coming from, turn off CSS and scripting, then look at your page:

> continent 
>   country 
>   population 
>   gdp 
>   asia+26826
>
> india1004
>
> china13020
>
> pakisthan201
>
> bangladesh181 Europe+1152
>
> UK215
>
> France416
>
> Germany521

It's not very clear, is it? Now present it as a `<table>`:

```
continent | country    | population | gdp
-----------------------------------------
asia      | india      | 100        | 4
          | china      | 130        | 20
          | pakistan   | 20         | 1
          | bangladesh | 18         | 1
-----------------------------------------
europe    | UK         | 2          | 15
          | france     | 1          | 16
          | germany    | 2          | 21
```

The data makes much more sense, and you can layer the extra features on top using CSS and javascript. Much better.

Comment: A sw have more number of hierarchies, doesn't it require more number of tds?? and we may need more calls of hide() function??

Comment: You can use `<tbody>` elements to break a table down into sections (is that what you mean by hierarchies?). `<th>` elements (instead of `td`) to mark a cell as a heading. You can use script to show/hide an entire `tbody`, `tr` or a whole collection of `tr` elements (you'd only need to call `hide()` once if you got the selector right). Additionally a `<th>` or `<td>` can span multiple rows and columns (`rowspan` and `colspan`) attributes if necessary.